# WPF data binding with delimited path, not updating target

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a custom WPF usercontrol which has a dependency property (snippet below). Which is not firing it's PropertyChangedCallback correctly.

CustomControl:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(float?), typeof(CustomControl),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDependencyPropertyChanged)));

public float? Value
{
    get { return (float?)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnDependencyPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // Do something
}
```

When I bind to the property with a simple path, all is fine. However when I use the delimited path syntax, the dependency property is not updated when it should be.

Working binding:

```
<namespace:CustomControl Value={Binding ViewModelProperty}/>
```

Not working binding:

```
<namespace:CustomControl Value={Binding ViewModelProperty.ObjectProperty}/>
```

With the working syntax, the OnDependencyPropertyChanged event handler is called in response to PropertyChanged events for ViewModelProperty fired by the view model. However with the 2nd syntax the OnDependencyPropertyChanged event handler is only called for changes to ObjectProperty, and is not called for changes to ViewModelProperty. Do I need to do any additional setup to make the delimited (.) path syntax work appropriately? (Have the same behavior that properties like TextBox.Text have by default)

Comment: Are you sure that a PropertyChanged event is fired for ViewModelProperty in the second case? And is it maybe possible that the new `ViewModelProperty` contains the same `ObjectProperty` value as the old one? In that case the binding won't be updated.

Comment: Yes the PropertyChanged event is definitely fired for ViewModelProperty in the second case. It is also true that the ObjectProperty value before and after has the same "float?" value, but I still expect the callback to occur (as equivalent is observable for TextBox.Text). As you state below "As long as there is a change notification for ViewModelProperty the binding will be updated".

Comment: How would you observe that `TextBox.Text` was updated when `ObjectProperty` contains the same `float` value? In the end, your PropertyChangedCallback is not called simply because the property value has not changed.

Comment: As an example of TextBox.Text updating even though the value hasn't actually changed, consider binding Text to ViewModelProperty.ObjectProperty, if a non-numeric value is entered the validation fails and ObjectProperty is not updated, however if a "ViewModelProperty" PropertyChanged event is fired the textbox resets to value of ObjectProperty (even though the value is the same before and after the "ViewModelProperty" PropertyChanged event)

Comment: Yes, but that is a completely different scenario. We are talking about a one-way binding here where the source property is notified to be changed, but actually has not changed its value.

Comment: I should have specified that my bindings are TwoWay

Comment: Apparently that doesn't change anything. The dependency property value hasn't changed, hence the callback isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your binding with the Path attribute?

```
<nmspc:CustomControl Value="{Binding Path=ViewModelProperty.ObjectProperty}" />
```

I recall that when building a two-way binding programatically the Path attribute is required.